# Cannot resolve dependencies 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'

Tags: android, gradle

In my project, I am trying to build auto image slider view
I am using SliderView library. And I added dependency from github:

```
implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'
```

But when add this dependency in project and sync the project, and try to use this library in my xml file. This library not appear although the project is build successfully.

Build.gradle(app):

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nctr.cd.bmvp"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.gitee.archermind-ti:autoimageslider:1.0.0-beta'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // room database dependency
    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    //retrofit http client dependency
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    //swipe refresh dependency to add pull to refresh for recycleView
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    // dependency for gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'

       // dependency for loading image from url

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

    // google service dependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    // auto image slider dependency
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `build.gradle` file so we can check what's going on there? Also, are you using multi-module project? Are you adding this dependency in the correct `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check  if `jcenter()` repositories is missing in your build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //here
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
   
    }
}
```

And also make sure that your project is on appcompat dependencies.

Comment: yes I am add    jcenter() in setting.gradle and this is work fine . thanks. much

Comment: Does it mean that you have solved it or the error still there?

Comment: yes its solve the problem and the error gone. thanks @Skizo

Comment: JCenter Maven repository is no longer receiving updates

Comment: 'jcenter(): MavenArtifactRepository!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java